# How to use js onclick function with data binding ? [Framework7]

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build, html-framework-7, dom7

I'm using Framework7 with the cordova social sharing plugin and I’m trying to use it onclick like this :

```
<a onclick='window.plugins.socialsharing.share("{{event_url}}")' class="link"><i class="material-icons md-only">share</i></a>
```

Also, with my infinite scroll, I append new cards to DOM like that :

```
<a onclick=\'window.plugins.socialsharing.share("'+data[i].event_url+'")\' class="link"><i class="material-icons md-only">share</i></a>
```

But when I build it, only the second one works, The first one open the cordova share but the content is empty !

Looks like it’s a quote issue but, but I don’t understand how to solve this..

Do you know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution (but still  weird..)

I had to add `target="_system"` and `external` class to my link